# How to fix 'setting true/false/value instead of null in mongodb using mongoose, nodejs and reactjs'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, http-post

I'm trying to update my MongoDB database using nodejs express and React. But instead of updating, the value is setting null.

It's updating well when I do the post request in postman or somewhere else.

**In expressjs**

```
//@route UPDATE api/todos/:id
app.post("/api/todos/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  Todo.findOne({ _id: id })
    .update({
      completed: req.body.completed
    })
    .then(res.json({ updated: true }))
    .catch(err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

**In Reactjs**

```
//completed: true/false <- updated
axios.post(`api/todos/${id}`, {
  _id: id,
  update: { title: updated }
});
```

**I've tried .patch instead of .post, yet didn't solve the problem.**

The expected result should be true/false, But it sets null.

Note: *It happens not only for the true/false value but also for another value.*

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with this code,

**Wrong data capture:**

You are sending `{_id:id, update: {title: updated}`
Which means in the `req.body` there will be two keys `_id` and `updated`
In your route it should be (refering [`Doc`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)):

```
app.post("/api/todos/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { _id, updated } = req.params;
  Todo.update({ _id }, updated )
    .then(()=>res.json({ updated: true }))
    .catch(err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

**Wrong Callback:**

```
.then(res.json({ updated: true }))
```

This is wrong, because `then` expects function pointer. `function(){}`

In your case, `res.json({ updated: true })()` is being called because it thinks `res.json({ updated: true })` is the function.

Change it to:

```
.then(()=>res.json({ updated: true }))
```